# How do I get a Flow to update a file attachment in a SharePoint list or library?

Tags: sharepoint, attachment, power-automate

I've been tasked with creating a time tracker and approval process for my organization. The basics are: around 130 employees, 6 managers; the employees are exempt and non-exempt; clock in and clock out everyday (clock in and out for lunch as well for the non-exempt employees). The clock-in and -out methods will be via smartphone, or if smartphone not an option, then at a computer. For the days an employee is out, they will have to submit an absence form. Therefore at the end of the week all clock-ins plus any absence forms (if applicable) will equal 40 hours.

I created a SharePoint list (TimeTracker) and a document library (TimeTrackerDepositoryLibrary) for document storage. I also created a button that will trigger the process for clock in and out. I also added a file option attachment to the trigger. Then created the Flow to update the list and attach a file to the same record if any. After that, notifications go out.

I cannot figure out how to get the file attachment to update or to be created/attached to the SharePoint list or the library with the user's record. What am I doing wrong?

I see that there are options to have that file attachment processed thru PowerApps or thru e-mail, but I do not want the users to go thru either of those methods.

I'm trying to figure out the attachment problem from above and then will move on to the other aspects of the process such as overtime flags, overtime approval, e-mails to managers for approval of work week hours, etc.

Please help with the attachment issue.

[image: Current Process Flow]

Answer (score 0):

The steps for this are pretty straightforward, but the trick is that the SharePoint item needs to be created first.  After that, use an Add attachment action where the ID comes from the previous Create item action.  The File Content is just the "File Content" from your trigger.

Comment: This can be helpful...                                           
                                                                            
                                                       
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-email-with-attaching-file-from-SharePoint-library-document/m-p/88496#M8728

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the Flow `Add Attachments` Action.
Your Flow should look like this:
[image]